# render JSON response using Jade

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, pug

i have gone back to basics to try and create a simple example of calling a REST API, receiving some JSON back and rendering the JSON data in HTML using Jade.

I have tried many approaches to this but cannot get any to work.

what code would i need to add to my main script file (below - lxrclient.js) to achieve this. I know i need to add express module, and render the view, but no matter who may approaches i have tried i cannot get it to work. I have also added the jade file i am using further down. really appreciate any help anyone can provide with this.

```js
//this is my main script file lxrclient3.js

var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var options = {
    host: '41.193.214.130',
    port: 2510,
    path: '/eiftidemo/clt_list',
    method: 'GET'
};


http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    //node of these statemnst excecute

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var clientsData = JSON.parse(body);
        debugger;

    });
}).end();

app.get("/clientlist", function(req, res){
   res.render('listlxr', {clientd: clientsData});
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Our App is running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

here is my Jade view

```js
html
  head
    title List of Clients
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")  
  body
    div.row
      div.col-md-3
      div.col-md-6
        div.panel.panel-primary
          div.panel-heading.text-center
            h1 Client List for Hyposure
          div.panel-body
            table.table
              each clients in clientsData
                tr
                  td.media
                    span.bg-info= clients.clientName
                  td.media
                    span.bg-info= clients.clientSurname
```

thx to anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you say Jade I hope you mean Pug, if not, you should update to the newest version of Pug instead.

Now, to send data to your template for the engine to render you send a JSON object, like so;

```
res.get("/", function(req, res)
{
   res.render("page.html", {greet : "Hello"});
}
```

This is a standard way of rendering a page and sending some data along side.

Now in your Pug (Jade (Same thing)) template you can access the sent variable like so;

```
html
 head
  title List of Clients
    body
     h1 #{greet} <!-- This will print "Hello" -->
```

This should give you a basic idea on how to render data onto a site, you can also send nested objects and you just work it the same way as in this example, but you point to the correct key. So for example if you're sending the following object:

```
{
  greet: {
    message : "Hello",
    who : "Adrian"
  }
}
```

Then you can print values from that using:

```
#{greet.message} #{greet.who}
```

Comment: many thx. my problem is that when i added res.get("/", function(req, res)
{
   res.render("page.html", {greet : "Hello"});
}
after my end stamens last time, it gave me an error that it cannot find the variable that contains the JSON

Comment: Where exactly did you add it? From the code you provided you are not using Express as your server base. The variable res in that case is undefined as that should be the variable which stores the express server.

Comment: I amended the script to hopefully get the flow right and render the view. unfortunately i am sort of back to where i have ended up with all my previous attempts, in that i cannot get the clientsData JSON to the view as it seems to disappear after the http.request section. so i get an error at that app.get line saying that clientsData is not defined! hohum...